# Adding Google Maps co-ordinates/markers from a custom map link

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I would like to know if you can input a URL of a custom map that was created through Google Maps and then show all the waypoints in your app without having to manually add them all.

Here's an example - https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zD38FaCAJQek.k_FDpSYzC2wI

What would be the fastest way to input all of those markers/waypoints and co-ordinates into my Android app that uses the Maps API? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To be exact, what you wanted to do is show markers on a map created with Google My Maps.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the Android Google Maps API can read KML files directly, so importing these files into your app is not possible.

One thing you could do, though it is quite a bit of work, is export your created map's KML file and read it programmatically. Extract the coordinates you need and add them as markers into your app.

Comment: if you agree with this, you should look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931281/open-local-kml-file-in-google-maps-on-android

Comment: Looks good. Do take note though that it will launch the Maps app, not load the map into your own app.