# Create a link in web page that permit to open google earth and/or google maps with loading a specified kml file

Tags: html, google-maps, google-earth

I'm trying to create a link in a web page that permit to open google maps and/or google earth loading the kml file specified.
I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931281/open-local-kml-file-in-google-maps-on-android) geouri method but don't seems working anymore with kml file
I also saw for example this:
https://earth.google.com/web/?kml=https://tourbuilder.withgoogle.com/tours/ahJzfmd3ZWItdG91cmJ1aWxkZXJyEQsSBFRvdXIYgICg6vjqywkM/earth
but this method seems working only with specific sites like tourbuilder, and for what I need, kml generated dynamically from the web pages, possibly updated over time and numerous kml (almost 200) would take a long time to create a "tour" for each (if that is possible) and would restrict the possible changes to the web page and to kml.

Can someone tell me if there is another way to create a link in a web page that permit to open google maps and/or google earth loading the kml file specified please?

Comment: Where is you KML? Stored locally, or on a publicly available domain?

Comment: in a publicly available domain

Comment: Whitelisted domains only, as you may already know, for example, https://earth.google.com/web/?kml=https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/KML_Samples.kml

Answer (score 0):

Maps.google.com used to support loading public KMLs via the search bar or via a URL parameter, but not anymore.  To load a KML in Google Maps, you need a web site (can be very simple) that uses the Maps API and loads a KML Layer.  Sounds like not your use-case, but if it was a simple KML that wouldn't be changing often, you could consider uploading it to a MyMap and sharing that.

Google Earth for web & mobile (as opposed to the Earth Pro desktop application) does not currently support loading arbitrary KMLs via URL either, except for certain KML sources (as you saw with tourbuilder).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I already use google maps api load kml ecc...

Comment: but for use term "(d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features" seems I can't try to create for example something for navigation help, I should use google maps instead loading kml in it but if is not supported anymore as you reply, seems that target like this can't be reached :(, or I'm wrong?