# Open KML/GPX files in appropriate external map app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kml, gpx

My Flutter (Android and iOS) app generates KML or GPX files, which works as expected.

Now I want to add a button "Open file" which should open such a system dialog where the installed map or other consuming apps (which can handle such formats) are listed to be chosen.

How can I open this dialog? How can I find the format-related apps and how can I send the file to these apps. I guess, there is a plugin for this, but couldn't find one. It must work on Android and iOS, nice-to have is web support.

I just saw [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) but I am not quite sure, if it works as expected because it doesn't list support for KML/GPX.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to launch an app using URI of the file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965747/android-how-to-open-google-maps-with-intent-and-kml?lq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345605/how-to-open-an-application-from-a-flutter-app

Comment: Nice idea, tried it, but `canLaunch(...)` is false unfortunately :( The error is `PlatformException(ACTIVITY_NOT_FOUND, No Activity found to handle intent {the\path\to\the\KML\file.kml}, null, null)` However, there are apps installed which can handle KML: Google Maps, Locus, ... and c:geo can handle GPX files

Comment: When I add `file:///`, I get a `android.os.FileUriExposedException`. When searching for a solution, I find, that I have to add a `provider` to my AndroidManifest, but this doesn't help...

Comment: Wouldn't it just be adding the MIME type of KML and GPX to the "open_file" plugin?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do this. Especially I don't know any specific MIME type for GPX.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format and as the [open_file Flutter plugin is open source](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file) you could fork it and add it in (just look for the other mime types in the files) or put in a feature request.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Would you mind to write this into an answer to earn the bounty?

Answer (score 1):

If you found a [Flutter plug-in](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) that is open source like [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file), you could just add in the MIME types yourself.

For KML format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language

For GPX format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format

As the package is open source I was thinking of modifying the code, as the mapping appears to be straight forward:

https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/blob/master/ios/Classes/OpenFilePlugin.m

and

https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/crazecoder/openfile/OpenFilePlugin.java

You would need to fork the projects and add in the types you wanted.

Alternately you've posted [issue ticket #116](https://github.com/crazecoder/open_file/issues/116)

where the repo owner responded with

> OpenFile.open("/sdcard/example.txt", type: "text/plain", uti: "public.plain-text");

Do respond if that works, as I was uncertain if both of the different platforms' filetype (`uti` vs MIME type) works universally in Flutter or if you have platform specific detection code to assign the filetype correctly.